# What measures the y-axis in stat_smooth, ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, ggplot2

I am fairly new with logistic regression. I have a binary response. And did this plot. The binary response is:

Y = 0: The student fails

Y = 1: The student succeed

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = both, aes(x = age, y = succeed)) + 
  stat_smooth(method = 'glm', family = 'binomial') +
  theme_bw()+xlab("X")+ylab("The student succeed")
```

[image]

**What is the y-axis? estimated probability that the student succeed? Or estimated log odds of a student succeed?
Feeling a little confused. Could someone explain what they are I have on the y-axis?**

Answer (score 2):

The y-axis is measured on the response scale, i.e. probability of success.

The help page for `stat_smooth` hints at this, but states that the prediction method is currently undocumented:

> Calculation is performed by the (currently undocumented) predictdf
>   generic function and its methods. For most methods the confidence
>   bounds are computed using the predict method - the exceptions are
>   loess which uses a t-based approximation, and for glm where the normal
>   confidence interval is constructed on the link scale, and then
>   back-transformed to the response scale.

`ggplot2:::predictdf.glm` shows that `predict` is used to generate predictions in the link scale, but these are then transformed to the response scale using the inverse link function.